# Microsoft Dynamics CRM Unique Nonclustered Indexes

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I've inherited a Dynamics CRM system at work, running: **Version 1612 (8.2.2.112) (DB 8.2.2.112) on-premises**.

We're in a situation where duplication seems to be happening intermittently via failed form submissions, with a subsequent re-submission. We've internally released a document explaining this behaviour and expressed how important it is to check first if some or all of the transaction actually succeeded. But humans will be humans, and often forget...

With that said, as a DBA, my first instinct was to create a unique constraint/index. However, it's not clear to me how to best accomplish this in the scope of Dynamics. I'm not confident in the application-level Duplication Detection that's available built-in, and Alternate Keys don't work for us since many of our unique constraints require the inclusion of a `DATE` field or two.

From what I can tell, adding indexes to the CRM base tables is a supported DML action, but indicates that it prevents upgrades. Does this mean that we can't upgrade in the future? Or simply that the indexes will not be migrated during the upgrade?

> Are there better solutions that I'm missing, which offer database-level consistency and don't impede upgrades?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With on-premise CRM you can add indexes, and it does not specify that this does not extend to clustered indexes. I very strongly recommend indexing CRM databases for performance. Per the developers guide:

> For Microsoft Dynamics 365 on-premises deployments, adding indexes is
>   supported per the guidelines in the Deploying and administering
>   Microsoft Dynamics CRM documentation. This applies to all Microsoft
>   Dynamics 365 databases and the Microsoft Dynamics 365 for Outlook
>   local database.

(I don't actually see anything related to indexes in the documentation mentioned above)

I am not sure which documentation you are referencing regarding upgrades not supporting these indexes, I have never experienced any difficulty upgrading CRM orgs with databases I indexed. However, there are apparently issues with upgrading to v9 related to full text indexes:
https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/242951

Also if you ever move to CRM online, this entire approach will no longer work.

The approach which IS supported with all CRM environments is to write a synchronous pre-operation plugin which checks your uniqueness condition, and throws an InvalidPluginExecutionException. This exception can include a user friendly message which the user will receive in the standard error pop up window when they try to create a duplicate. This is guaranteed to be nicer experience than whatever happens when the application violates an index constraint.

I enforce contact email address uniqueness using this method and it works very nicely. I have a duplicate detection rule set up, and if the user ignores the duplicate warning and creates the contact anyway, they receive a message that duplicate email addresses are not allowed.